# Can I configure worked EJabberd without using 5269 port? blocked by provider

Tags: ejabberd

Is it possible to make ejabberd.yml and ejabberdctl.cfg files to use another ports or except using port 5269?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these steps:

### listen:
...

```
port: 3478
transport: udp
module: ejabberd_stun
```

- port: 3478
  module: ejabberd_stun
- port: 5349
  module: ejabberd_stun
  certfile: /etc/ejabberd/server.pem
  ...

Example:

https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/listen/

Answer (score 0):

Your network provider blocks port 5269?
It's the standard port number for XMPP server-2-server connections.

When some user in a remote XMPP server wants to chat with somebody in your ejabberd server, by default they will attempt to connect to your ejabberd on port number 5269, so your ejabberd should be listening in port 5269, and that port should not be blocked... bad luck!

Of course, you can edit that 5269 number in ejabberd.yml, put whatever like 555269, and ejabberd will listen in that different port number... but remote servers will still attempt to contact ejabberd on port 5269, so that connection will fail!

Searching for some way to tell remote XMPP servers to contact you to a different port number, it seems you can set up SRV DNS records when you run s2s over a custom port, see https://prosody.im/doc/s2s and https://prosody.im/doc/dns